# Change file extensions of multiple files in a directory with terminal/bash?

Tags: iphone, bash, terminal, file-extension, launch-daemon

I'm developing a simple launchdaemon that copies files from one directory to another. I've gotten the files to transfer over fine.

I just want the files in the directory to be .mp3's instead of .dat's

Some of the files look like this:

> 6546785.8786.dat
>   3678685.9834.dat
>   4658679.4375.dat

I want them to look like this:

> 6546785.8786.mp3
>   3678685.9834.mp3
>   4658679.4375.mp3

This is what I have at the end of the bash script to rename the file extensions.

```
cd $mp3_dir
mv *.dat *.mp3
exit 0
```

Problem is the file comes out as *.mp3 instead of 6546785.8786.mp3

and when another 6546785.8786.dat file is imported to $mp3_dir, the *.mp3 is overwritten with the new .mp3

I need to rename **just** the .dat file extensions to .mp3 and keep the filename.

Ideas? Suggestions?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try:

```
for file in *.dat; do mv "$file" "${file%dat}mp3"; done
```

Or, if your shell has it:

```
rename .dat .mp3 *.dat
```

Now, why your command didn't work: first of all, it is more than certain that you only had one file in your directory when it was renamed to `*.mp3`, otherwise `mv` would have failed with `*.mp3: not a directory`.

And mv does NOT do any magic with file globs, it is the *shell* which expands globs. Which means, if you had this file in the directory:

```
t.dat
```

and you typed:

```
mv *.dat *.mp3
```

the shell would have expanded `*.dat` to `t.dat`. However, as nothing would match `*.mp3`, the shell would have left it as is, meaning the fully expanded command is:

```
mv t.dat *.mp3
```

Which will create a file named, literally, `*.mp3`.

If, on the other hand, you had *several* files named `*.dat`, as in:

```
t1.dat t2.dat
```

the command would have expanded to:

```
mv t1.dat t2.dat *.mp3
```

But this will fail: if there are more than two arguments to `mv`, it expects the last argument (ie, `*.mp3`) to be a directory.

Comment: That worked great. I swear I thought I searched the entire internet for the right answer. Thanks so much. Now I need to figure out how to name this .mp3's to the name of the song automatically.

Comment: No problem :) See also the edit, there is another nicer command to do it. And don't forget to accept the answer ;)

Comment: +1. If you put variables into "doublequote" it will also work for filenames with spaces.

Comment: @fge I want to do the same, but insert '@2x' just before the extension instead. But I end up with 'picture.png@2x.png' if I add the dot after the % in the command. Can you help?

Comment: Fixed by using 'rename', installed with homebrew :)

Comment: All above fails in Ubuntu. Correct syntax for me in Ubuntu was `rename s/"SEARCH"/"REPLACE"/g  *`

Answer (score 18):

For anyone on a mac, this is quite easy if you have BREW, if you don't have brew then my advice is get it. then when installed just simply do this

```
$ brew install rename
```

then once rename is installed just type (in the directory where the files are)

```
$ rename -s dat mp3 *
```