# Regarding changing the file extensions of all files in a folder in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: file

I have a folder containing number of files with extensions in .xvg format and i need to change them into .dat format. How can i do that..?

What are the commands that i need to give such that all those files extensions that are in .xvg format are converted into .dat format [without the file name getting changed,(example., abc.xvg should be converted into abc.dat),only file extension should be changed].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change file extensions of multiple files in a directory with terminal/bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551993/change-file-extensions-of-multiple-files-in-a-directory-with-terminal-bash)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`rename 's/.xvg$/.dat/' *.xvg`

For a test run you can use this command:

`rename 's/.xvg$/.dat/' *.xvg -vn`

`-v` means "verbose" and it will output the names of the files when it renames them.

`-n` will do a test run where it won't rename any files, But will show you a list of files that would be renamed.